How can FileSystemWatcher detect deletions from multiple volumes?
I wrote a program which can open or empty the recycle bin and lives in the tray. I am using SHEmptyRecycleBin to perform cleaning and FileSystemWatcher to detect changes in the recycle bin folder. The problem is that FileSystemWatcher does not react when I delete a file not from C disk. I would be grateful for your help!
Part of the code:
enum RecycleFlags : uint
{
    SHRB_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x00000001,
    SHRB_NOPROGRESSUI = 0x00000002,
    SHRB_NOSOUND = 0x00000004
}

[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr hwnd, string pszRootPath, RecycleFlags dwFlags);

static Shell shell = new Shell();
Folder recycleBin = shell.NameSpace(10);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\\$Recycle.Bin");

    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (recycleBin.Items().Count == 0)
    {
        NotifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        NotifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Full;
    }
}

private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "shell:RecycleBinFolder");
}

private void emptyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, RecycleFlags.SHRB_NOSOUND);
}


Each volume has its own $Recycle.Bin folder. Your code only monitors the C: drive.

You need to create a watcher for each drive.

Soft-deletes are essentially Rename operations that make a file or folder appear inside the volume's Recycle Bin. That's why they're fast. If the files had to be moved to a central location you'd have to wait for the data to get copied. Imagine deleting a 900MB file

@PanagiotisKanavos the main purpose of my program is simply to "move" the recycle bin to the tray to remove the recycle bin shortcut from the desktop

When shell.NameSpace(10) represents a virtual folder for all drives with enabled recycle bin (not sure about that) i would simply drop the FileSystemWatcher and replace it with a Timer checking the count of that one.

@Ralf I'm worried about performance issues with the timer. Does it put a lot of strain on the system?

FileSystemWatcher does that also. And in a system under pressure it will drop certain events then so you don't get notified of changes. So you can't trust it completely.  I'm not aware about the cost asking the shell about recycle bin usage. But i don't see that this needs to be exactly on time. So i assume a timer running every Minute or so shouldn't be a problem.

The problem is that you are only monitoring the C drive. As you have correctly determined, there is the $Recycle.Bin folder on C. Depending on the file system, it also exists on other drives. You have to monitor this folder. From a technical point of view, it would be very time-consuming to move the data (especially large files or many small files) to C first. For a move within a hard disk (patetion) you have to change the patetion table.

As I was prompted above, I only tracked changes to the recycle bin on the C drive. Perhaps my solution is not the best, but since I made this program for myself, I just added another FileSystemWatcher for the Recycle Bin on drive D.
FileSystemWatcher CDriveWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\\$Recycle.Bin");

CDriveWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
CDriveWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

FileSystemWatcher DDriveWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\\$Recycle.Bin");

DDriveWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
DDriveWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

